# Retrying deadlocks in a loop, will they eventually resolve?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, locking

If I write code in a PL/SQL function which upon catching a ORA-00060 deadlock exception (Oracle 10g), just rolls back and retries the transaction, will, such a function complete in a finite amount of time (you can assume that the work to be done by the database is finite, not an infinite stream)?

Is there any particular reason why I should add a wait before retrying?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it depends on what other transactions in the system, especially the other(s) involved in the deadlock, are doing.  You could have a situation where the second attempt would block indefinitely due to locked resources, or even encounter a second deadlock.

At the very least, before implementing this solution, I think you should understand how the deadlock is arising and consider what is likely to happen in the other sessions involved when the first session gets the exception.